# Python - Beautiful Soup Returning Errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to extract the covers for different journals on the cambridge university press website. The I want to save it as it's online ISSN. The following code works but after one or two journals, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection
.py", line 141, in _new_conn
    (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\conne
ction.py", line 60, in create_connection
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 745, in getaddr
info
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection
pool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection
pool.py", line 357, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1239, in r
equest
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1285, in _
send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1234, in e
ndheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 1026, in _
send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\http\client.py", line 964, in se
nd
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection
.py", line 166, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection
.py", line 150, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x030DB770>: Fai
led to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.
py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection
pool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry
.py", line 388, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='ore', port=80): Max retries exceeded with
 url: /services/aop-file-manager/file/57f386d3efeebb2f18eac486 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urlli
b3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x030DB770>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110
04] getaddrinfo failed',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Boys\Documents\Python\python_work\Kudos\CUPgetcovers.py", line 19, in <module>
    f.write(requests.get("http://" + imagefound).content)
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py",
line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.
py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.
py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Boys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.
py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='ore', port=80): Max retries exceeded w
ith url: /services/aop-file-manager/file/57f386d3efeebb2f18eac486 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<ur
llib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x030DB770>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
11004] getaddrinfo failed',))

Process returned 1 (0x1)        execution time : 4.373 s
Press any key to continue . . .
```

What am I doing wrong? I could not find any answers on google. It was working fine before.
Thank you in advance.

Edit:
launch.py:

```
    import httplib2
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
    import csv
    import requests
    from time import sleep

    with open('listoflinks.csv', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in readCSV:
            http = httplib2.Http()
            status, response = http.request(("https://www.cambridge.org" + row[0]))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response, "html.parser")
            txt = (t.text for t in soup.find_all("span", class_="value"))
            issn = next(t[:9] for t in txt if t.endswith("(Online)"))
            for a in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'class' : 'image'}):
                if a.img:
                    imagefound = (a.img['src'])
                    imagefound = imagefound[2:]
                    f = open((issn + ".jpg"),'wb')
                    f.write(requests.get("http://" + imagefound).content)
                    f.close()
```

listoflinks.csv:

```
/core/journals/journal-of-materials-research
/core/journals/journal-of-mechanics
/core/journals/journal-of-modern-african-studies
/core/journals/journal-of-navigation
/core/journals/journal-of-nutritional-science
/core/journals/journal-of-pacific-rim-psychology
/core/journals/journal-of-paleontology
/core/journals/journal-of-pension-economics-and-finance
/core/journals/journal-of-plasma-physics
/core/journals/journal-of-policy-history
/core/journals/journal-of-psychologists-and-counsellors-in-schools
/core/journals/journal-of-public-policy
/core/journals/journal-of-race-ethnicity-and-politics
/core/journals/journal-of-radiotherapy-in-practice
/core/journals/journal-of-relationships-research
/core/journals/journal-of-roman-archaeology
/core/journals/journal-of-roman-studies
/core/journals/journal-of-smoking-cessation
/core/journals/journal-of-social-policy
/core/journals/journal-of-southeast-asian-studies
/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic
/core/journals/journal-of-the-american-philosophical-association
/core/journals/journal-of-the-australian-mathematical-society
/core/journals/journal-of-the-gilded-age-and-progressive-era
/core/journals/journal-of-the-history-of-economic-thought
/core/journals/journal-of-the-institute-of-mathematics-of-jussieu
/core/journals/journal-of-the-international-neuropsychological-society
/core/journals/journal-of-the-international-phonetic-association
/core/journals/journal-of-the-marine-biological-association-of-the-united-kingdom
/core/journals/journal-of-the-royal-asiatic-society
/core/journals/journal-of-the-society-for-american-music
/core/journals/journal-of-tropical-ecology
/core/journals/journal-of-tropical-psychology
/core/journals/journal-of-wine-economics
/core/journals/kantian-review
/core/journals/knowledge-engineering-review
/core/journals/language-and-cognition
/core/journals/language-in-society
/core/journals/language-teaching
/core/journals/language-variation-and-change
/core/journals/laser-and-particle-beams
/core/journals/latin-american-antiquity
/core/journals/latin-american-politics-and-society
/core/journals/law-and-history-review
/core/journals/legal-information-management
/core/journals/legal-studies
/core/journals/legal-theory
/core/journals/leiden-journal-of-international-law
/core/journals/libyan-studies
/core/journals/lichenologist
/core/journals/lms-journal-of-computation-and-mathematics
/core/journals/macroeconomic-dynamics
/core/journals/management-and-organization-review
/core/journals/mathematical-gazette
/core/journals/mathematical-proceedings-of-the-cambridge-philosophical-society
/core/journals/mathematical-structures-in-computer-science
/core/journals/mathematika
/core/journals/medical-history
/core/journals/medical-history-supplements
/core/journals/melanges-d-histoire-sociale
/core/journals/microscopy-and-microanalysis
/core/journals/microscopy-today
/core/journals/mineralogical-magazine
/core/journals/modern-american-history
/core/journals/modern-asian-studies
/core/journals/modern-intellectual-history
/core/journals/modern-italy
/core/journals/mrs-advances
/core/journals/mrs-bulletin
/core/journals/mrs-communications
/core/journals/mrs-energy-and-sustainability
/core/journals/mrs-online-proceedings-library-archive
/core/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal
/core/journals/natural-language-engineering
/core/journals/netherlands-journal-of-geosciences
/core/journals/network-science
/core/journals/new-perspectives-on-turkey
/core/journals/new-surveys-in-the-classics
/core/journals/new-testament-studies
/core/journals/new-theatre-quarterly
/core/journals/nineteenth-century-music-review
/core/journals/nordic-journal-of-linguistics
/core/journals/numerical-mathematics-theory-methods-and-applications
/core/journals/nutrition-research-reviews
/core/journals/organised-sound
/core/journals/oryx
/core/journals/paleobiology
/core/journals/the-paleontological-society-papers
/core/journals/palliative-and-supportive-care
/core/journals/papers-of-the-british-school-at-rome
/core/journals/parasitology
/core/journals/parasitology-open
/core/journals/personality-neuroscience
/core/journals/perspectives-on-politics
/core/journals/philosophy
/core/journals/phonology
/core/journals/plainsong-and-medieval-music
/core/journals/plant-genetic-resources
/core/journals/polar-record
/core/journals/political-analysis
/core/journals/political-science-research-and-methods
/core/journals/politics-and-gender
/core/journals/politics-and-religion
/core/journals/politics-and-the-life-sciences
/core/journals/popular-music
/core/journals/powder-diffraction
/core/journals/prehospital-and-disaster-medicine
/core/journals/primary-health-care-research-and-development
/core/journals/probability-in-the-engineering-and-informational-sciences
/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-asil-annual-meeting
/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-edinburgh-mathematical-society
/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-international-astronomical-union
/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-nutrition-society
/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-prehistoric-society
/core/journals/proceedings-of-the-royal-society-of-edinburgh-section-a-mathematics
/core/journals/ps-political-science-and-politics
/core/journals/psychological-medicine
/core/journals/public-health-nutrition
/core/journals/publications-of-the-astronomical-society-of-australia
/core/journals/quarterly-reviews-of-biophysics
/core/journals/quaternary-research
/core/journals/queensland-review
/core/journals/radiocarbon
/core/journals/ramus
/core/journals/recall
/core/journals/religious-studies
/core/journals/renewable-agriculture-and-food-systems
/core/journals/review-of-international-studies
/core/journals/review-of-middle-east-studies
/core/journals/review-of-politics
/core/journals/review-of-symbolic-logic
/core/journals/revista-de-historia-economica-journal-of-iberian-and-latin-american-economic-history
/core/journals/robotica
/core/journals/royal-historical-society-camden-fifth-series
/core/journals/royal-institute-of-philosophy-supplements
/core/journals/rural-history
/core/journals/science-in-context
/core/journals/scottish-journal-of-theology
/core/journals/seed-science-research
/core/journals/slavic-review
/core/journals/social-philosophy-and-policy
/core/journals/social-policy-and-society
/core/journals/social-science-history
/core/journals/spanish-journal-of-psychology
/core/journals/studies-in-american-political-development
/core/journals/studies-in-church-history
/core/journals/studies-in-second-language-acquisition
/core/journals/tempo
/core/journals/theatre-research-international
/core/journals/theatre-survey
/core/journals/theory-and-practice-of-logic-programming
/core/journals/think
/core/journals/traditio
/core/journals/trans-trans-regional-and-national-studies-of-southeast-asia
/core/journals/transactions-of-the-royal-historical-society
/core/journals/transnational-environmental-law
/core/journals/twentieth-century-music
/core/journals/twin-research-and-human-genetics
/core/journals/urban-history
/core/journals/utilitas
/core/journals/victorian-literature-and-culture
/core/journals/visual-neuroscience
/core/journals/weed-science
/core/journals/weed-technology
/core/journals/wireless-power-transfer
/core/journals/world-politics
/core/journals/world-s-poultry-science-journal
/core/journals/world-trade-review
/core/journals/zygote
```

Comment: The part of the error you should concentrate on is `Max retries exceeded with url`.

Comment: So how do I fix it?

Comment: Without your code, I can't comment. Also, just Google it or search on SO. There are many answers answering your quesiton.

Comment: I've put the code up now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simplify your code and your scraping strategy, although I can see that not all journal pages have the same structure. On most pages you can get the ISSN easily through a form value. On others (free access, I think) you need to apply some kind of heuristics to get the ISSN. Also I don't know why you are using httplib2 and requests as both provide more or less the same functionality. Anyway here's some code that does what you want ... kind of (I have also removed the CSV code because as it is there's not need for that):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

with open('listoflinks.csv', encoding="utf8") as f:
        for line in f:
            path = line.strip()
            print("getting", path)
            response = requests.get("https://www.cambridge.org" + path)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
            try:
               issn = soup.find("input", attrs={'name': 'productIssn'}).get('value')
            except:
               values = soup.find_all("span", class_="value")
               for v in values:
                  if "(Online)" in v.string:
                      issn = v.string.split(" ")[0]
                      break

            print("issn:", issn)
            details_container = soup.find("div", class_="details-container")
            image = details_container.find("img")
            imgurl = image['src'][2:]
            print("imgurl:", imgurl)
            with open(issn + ".jpg", 'wb') as output:
               output.write(requests.get("http://" + imgurl).content)
```